# Not saving plotly graph locally, but saving it to variable

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, bytesio

Is there a way to download multiple plotly graphs without saving them locally? They can be downloaded separately, not as zip.

that's what im came up with, but don't want to save them locally, just assign it to variable and send  it by dcc.send_file()

```
candles.write_image("images/figure.png")

indicator_chart.write_image("images/figure1.png")

indicator_chart2.write_image("images/figure2.png")

volume.write_image("images/figure3.png")

shutil.make_archive("images", "zip", "images")

return dcc.send_file("images.zip")
```

Comment: In your example you are saving the image of the figure as a file and you want users to be able to download it. Have you checked out https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/download? 
Also it's a little unclear whether you're okay with saving it as a file or not since your example does that.

Comment: My example is saving it locally to folder before downloading it, but I want to download it without saving file locally

Comment: I don't think you can do that since the file has to exist in order for someone to download it.